# changing return value for certain argument with guards

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements

I am trying to code a Haskell function that returns the number of days in a month, given the month and year. Here is what I currently have:

```
days :: Int -> Int -> Int
days month year
  month 1 = 31
  if ily year then month 2 = 29
  else month 2 = 28
```

The `ily` function is returning a `Bool` after determining whether the year is a leap year or not.

I kind of understand why this doesn't work but I'm unsure how to achieve what I am trying to. I'm essentially asking if there is a way to use conditionals to change the return value of a certain argument (in this case 2, or February).

Comment: Unrelated but `ily` should probably be called `isLeabYear`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've just got the syntax a little confused I think.

```
days :: Int -> Int -> Int
days 1 _                = 31 -- January always has 31 days
days 2 year | ily year  = 29 -- February during a leap year
            | otherwise = 28 -- February otherwise
days 3 _                = 31 -- March always has 31 days
days 4 _                = 30 -- April always has 30 days
...
```

Pattern matching at the function level is done by repeating the function name, then the arguments, and filling in any arguments you want to match against. *Guards* are indicated by following the function pattern with a vertical bar and then a conditional.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm pretty new to Haskell so I thought it'd be some kind of syntax error. I'll give this a try :)